# C# Chaining with Partial Repository Class

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have classes in my program like

```
class QueryUtil1{
 getByID(int id){
   //open connection
   //create query
  // map to dataset and return
 }
}
class QueryUtil2{
 getByID(int id){
   //open connection
   //create query
  // map to dataset and return
 }
}
```

so these methods calls from multiple classes creates multiple round trips to database like hundreds in some cases what I am trying to do is merge all those queries and return it in single dataset bu method chaining like

```
QueryUtil utill = new QueryUtil()l
Dataset ds = utill
._queryUtil1.getByID(id)
._queryUtil2.getByID(id)
.execute();
```

whose implementation is

```
class QueryUtil {
 StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
 QueryUtil1 _queryUtil1 = new QueryUtil1();
 QueryUtil2 _queryUtil2 = new QueryUtil2();

 execute(){
  string sql = query.ToString();
  //execute command and return dataset
 }
class QueryUtil1 : QueryUtil{
     QueryUtil getByID(int id){
       query.append("select * from table where id = " + id);
       return this;
     }
    }
}
```

**but the problem is it throws stackoverflowexeption because child class initiates parent class and parent class initiate child class and so on...
I want to achieve chaining any idea how to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the [composite pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) is your solution.

In any case, you need a "container" that store all your QueryUtil objects and manage them